# return statement in a Java for loop doesn't exit method

Tags: java, android, for-loop, return, control-flow

Stepping through the following code in Android Studio takes me first to the return account.name line and then to the return "" line! And empty string is returned from the method.

What am I missing?

```
//return the username (email address) of the first Google account for the testmobile.co.uk domain on the device
public static String getTestMobileAccountUserName(Context context)
{
    final String TEST_MOBILE_ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.google";
    final String TEST_MOBILE_GOOGLE_APPS_DOMAIN = "testmobile.co.uk";

    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(TEST_MOBILE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

    for (Account account: accounts)
    {
        if (account.name.endsWith("@" + TEST_MOBILE_GOOGLE_APPS_DOMAIN))
        {
            return account.name;
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

When I step through in the debugger, account.name is set to lalala@testmobile.co.uk on the return account.name line.

Comment: Surely none of the accounts name ends with @...

Comment: If `return account.name;` is really reached, `return "";` will definitely not be reached.

Comment: Add System.out.println(account.name); before the "if" statement and post the output.

Comment: I bet that return `return account.name;` is never invokend and you only think it is

Comment: @Djon - he's also appending testmobile.co.uk - so the test is really .endsWith("@testmobile.co.uk").  Which would be valid for an email address check.

Comment: @DanMatthews-Grout Yes obviously, `...` was an ellipsis, my bad. However, the test if on the `name`, and not the `address`, they might be the same but that could also be a problem.

Comment: @Djon - sorry mate - didn't see that.

Comment: @cja it would be so easy for a debug session to find out what `account.name` you find there. Or just print it, like Dan said, and see what happens....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a return statement is executed, the debug tool goes to the last statement of the method, but is not executed. If it returns "", is because account.name is "". Don't worry, both return are not executed.

Comment: No - it's not executing the first return because the condition in the "if" isn't met.

Comment: "... takes me first to the return account.name line and then ..." This is because if is met, doesn't?

Comment: Either he is mistaken or Java is broken.